# How to write documentation comments in ANSI C?

Tags: c, documentation, code-documentation

I can't find how to write comments in C. I mean I know about `//` and `/* */`, what I mean is where can I find good practices? Like if I have a function, how do I write the `@param variable is the value bla bla`, like it is done in Java?

Are there any standards for this? Or can I just do it like I do it in Java?

Comment: Actually, you can't even use `//` in ANSI C. Only from C99 did they allow `//`. (Though GCC allows it as an extension.)

Comment: Only `/* */` is supported in C. `//` is an addition in C++

Comment: The term "ANSI C" typically refers to the language described by the 1989 ANSI standard, but strictly speaking that's incorrect.  In 1990, ISO issued the same standard (with some new introductory material and renumbered sections), and ANSI adopted it.  In 1999, ISO issued a new C standard, and ANSI adopted it as well, rendering the 1989/1990 standard officially obsolete.  In late 2011, ISO issued another new C standard, which ANSI has also adopted.  Except for the first, C standards are initially published by ISO, not ANSI -- and it's best to refer to the standards by year.

Comment: Alas, there are still compilers that don't support even the 1999 ISO C standard.  Support for the 1990 standard is nearly universal.

Comment: @KeithThompson Very true - compilers still don't implement C++89 - I did not know C was going for a revamp too - I've been concentrating on C++0x (or C++11 as its now known). Seems there are very little changes - what a waste of time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many different standards, if you want to generate documentation, try [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)

Answer (score 12):

You can use javadoc standard and then use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) that understands javadoc to generate a documentation.

In doxygen I recommend using the option `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` set to `YES`. If the JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF tag is set to YES then doxygen will interpret the first line (until the first dot) of a Javadoc-style comment as the brief description.

Example for a class definition:

```
/**
 * A brief description. A more elaborate class description
 * @param bool somebool a boolean argument.
 * @see Test()
 * @return The test results
 */
```

(Some more examples [in the doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#docexamples))

Installation is really simple, there is a GUI and a nice graphical visualisation available with:

```
apt-get install doxygen doxygen-gui graphviz
```

Run the gui calling `doxywizard` and use the Wizard settings, only `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` has to be set there in "Expert" settings.

Comment: A nice answer with an example.

Answer (score 5):

There are no standards follow the standard which your company mandates.
A popular way to create documentation from projects is to use **[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)**.

Answer (score 3):

An option is to use the doxygen format of writing comments - this has the added benefit of being able to generate html/latex and other sorts of docs for your code.